# Charge a Magsafe MBP with a USBC power supply using an adaptor?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

We've got a few newer 15" MBPs (Macbook Pros) in our office, so we have a few USBC MBP chargers in various areas.

We also have some older magsafe (not magsafe 2) MBPs which are Late 2012 , 15" MBPs.

So that we dont need to put different chargers in each location, is it possible charge a Late 2012 MBP using a USBC charger with an adaptor of some type ?

Comment: Just a heads up that if they're not MagSafe 2, they must be 2nd generation or earlier, so Mid-2012 model or earlier; not Late 2012

Comment: Anyway, you're looking for [something like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07XMKFHB4). I can't vouch for that item, since I haven't used it or any other similar adaptors, and I'd advise that you don't try to get the cheapest one available, since cheaper ones may not be designed to communicate properly with the charger or the laptop's OneWire circuit in order to regulate the voltage, so cheaper ones may charge much more slowly; I *have* experienced such issues with cheap adapters that purport to support Qualcomm's Quick Charge standard. Having said that, the reviews seem mainly positive.